# What's the Scottish equivalent of the prefix "Anglo-"?

Tags: prefixes

Scotch gets misused and I don't want to join those ranks if it's incorrect.
Celtic seems to cover a wider area.
Pictish seems to be specific to the Northeast.
Gaelic I always assume to be Irish.

All of them seem to have pros and cons but I'm not sure any of them are correct.

Thanks.

Mike.

Edit:
This is for the next census form. Instead of the regular "British" under nationality, I want to put Scottish-European, or the equivelent.

Comment: Hint:  "Anglo" comes from *Angli*, the Latin name for the inhabitants there.  So what was the Latin name for the Scots?

Comment: Do you think the French or Germans add a -European or the equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explain why in particular you need this.  One answer would be to place the 'Scottish' in second place (Franco-Scottish).  Another is to use a hyphen.  For example, the Northern Irish descended from Scots who immigrated into Ireland in the 18th century are known as Scots-Irish.  Don't use 'Scotch', unless you are talking about whisky, a boiled egg fried in minced beef and egg crumbs or 'butter scotch'. the sweetie.  Many Scottish people find it offensive.

Comment: What about the adhesive tape? Or broth, pancakes, and certain hot peppers? Also, 'butterscotch' is one word.

Comment: Or [typeface genres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch_Roman).

Comment: It's for the next census - I want to put my nationality as Scottish-European but want to get the terminology correct. I've clarified the question.

Comment: I like Scots. Even I found Trump's misuse of "Scotch" offensive. My father was Scottish and I spent 25 years living in the US. Since returning and post-Brexit, I find myself identifying as more and more Scottish.

Comment: @Mike That sounds fine.  Personally I like the sound of 'Scots-European' better.  You will be aware that you count as Scottish as a civic (voting) member of the Kingdom of Scotland. Your European identity more of a personal matter (unless/until certain other things happen).   But Britain is and always has been a European country, much as some may ignore or deny the geographic fact.  I consider myself to be European now and always have, before Britain joined.  I am also English, though that is not my nationality.

Comment: @Mike - The Scottish Government says that "We plan that British citizens habitually resident in Scotland on independence will be considered Scottish citizens. This will include British citizens who hold dual citizenship with another country. Scottish born British citizens currently living outside of Scotland will also be considered Scottish citizens.". My wife and I have been researching house prices in Edinburgh.

Comment: The Scottish might not like it, but [in New York the settlers were known as "Scotch-Irish"](https://scottishsociety-sa.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/ScotsIrish.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

By analogy from Latin Hibernia giving Hiberno- for Irish, perhaps Caledonia could give Caledono- (so Caledono-French or Caledono-European)? This doesn't seem to be attested that I've been able to find though, but I'd expect it to be fairly well understood after a moment's thought at least in Scotland and probably in most of the UK.

Alternatively given Scotia is also ultimately Latin, Scoto- would probably also fit the bill here, at risk of not sounding quite as poetic (and possibly being read as a typo for Scots-).

Comment: Please realise that ELU deals solely with attested usages.

Comment: Ah, Caledonian was the word I couldn't put my finger on but I think, for clarity, I'll use Scots.

Comment: Provisional +1...interesting, but please provide some citations and sources.

Answer (score 0):

I think Albano- will do.
Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alba for more info.

Comment: Some have also used _Scoto-_ see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoto-Norman

Comment: I think, even if it's grammatically correct, that might give the impression that I'm from Albania! I had enough of dealing with immigration in the US to give them even a hint of that!

Comment: Please realise that ELU deals solely with attested usages.

Comment: That's fine, Edwin. I found while writing a novel just how limited the regimented English language is and the different techniques to add subtlety to meanings.